# Is it possible to change the architecture of an AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

We have this AMI with a AMD64 architecture, and we need to run it on a m6g.medium, the problem is this machine only runs aarch architecture.

**Is there a way to change the AMI architecture?**

What others solutions are out there?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't change the AMI architecture. It's a Graviton / ARM based CPU not Intel based. M6**G** stands for Graviton.

You will need to create a Graviton / ARM specific AMI. Start with a Graviton / ARM based operating system and install your applications / resources.